# How to merge items from flatMapIterable

Tags: java, rx-java

I have an infinite observable (db observer) that emits finite sequences of items, that need to be processed and then emitted back as a group.

The problem here is, how to write it so that `toList` doesn't wait for the original source to finish, but for the flatMapIterable generated sequence instead;

```
DbObservable.map(new Func1<Query, List<Item>>() {
                        @Override
                        public List<Item> call(Query query) {
                            return query.items; //get items from db query
                        }
                    })
                    .flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<Item>, Iterable<Item>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Iterable<Item> call(List<GeoStop> geoStops) {
                            return geoStops;
                        }
                    })
                    .flatMap(/*process*/)
                    .toList() // regenerate List that was passed in to flatMapIterable
                    //subscribe and emit list of items
```

Nothing reaches subscribers due to `toList` being stuck waiting for `DbObservable`'s `onComplete`.

Answer (score 6):

`toList()` waits for `onCompleted()` event but the `flatMap(/*process*/)` doesn't propagate complete.

So, you need to call them inside a new `flatMap()`

```
db.map(q -> q.items)
    .flatMap(items -> Observable.from(items)
        .flatMapIterable(items)
        .flatMap(/*process*/)
        .toList()
    )
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Could you explain the answer?

Answer (score 4):

You could process the List inside the first flatMap with the flatMap+toList:

```
db.map(q -> q.items)
  .flatMap(items -> Observable.from(items).flatMap(...).toList())
  .subscribe(...)
```